# Proper way to structure classes in Xcode framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, frameworks, controller

I'm building a custom Xcode framework, and I have a class called `AXController` that has a class method called `showActivationWindow`. `showActivationWindow` initializes and shows a window using `AXWindowController` which is a subclass of `NSWindowController`. Then, `AXWindowController` calls `activate` which is a class method in `AXController` on a button press in the window it displays.

I included `AXWindowController.h` in `AXController.h` and included `AXController.h` in `AXWindowController.h` so each could access the other's methods, but this is throwing a lot of Xcode warnings. It also seems like a very inelegant solution.

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to import header files recursively. There's a directive `@class` [(link to Apple doc)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1) which tells that there is a class named as such. In practice the usage is something like `A.h`

```
@class B;
@interface A:NSObject {
   B* anInstanceOfB;
} 
...
@end
```

and `B.h`

```
#import "A.h"
@interface B:NSObject {
  A* anInstanceOfA;
}
...
@end
```

Then you can import `A.h` and `B.h` as you like from your .m file! But be careful not to make a retain cycle, if you don't use garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my code to use `@class`. But I'm still getting warnings involving the following:  
  
In class A, I have `static NSString *appName;` outside of the `@interface`, and now I'm getting a warning that says "`appName` defined but not used."  
  
What does this warning mean and why am I getting it?

Comment: You may want to learn how to declare global variables in C. 
This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keword-in-c might be helpful. In a nutshell, in `A.h`, write `extern NSString*appName;`
In `A.m`, write `#import "A.h"` and then `NSString*appName;`
Finally, if you want to refer to appName from `B.h`, just do `#import "A.h"` inside `B.h`. I guess you want to have a class variable like C++, but `static` in C or Objective-C is something different, and it works differently.

Comment: Actually, after some researching, the correct way to declare class-level variables is as follows: `static NSString *myString` in A.m.

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables