# Application-wide variable access: static like Java?

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, static-variables

I have an instance variable in my view controller that I would like to share with the whole program. I'm not quite sure how to do this. Can I just declare it as a static instance variable and then access it through properties like `ViewControllerClass.instancevariable`?

Thanks!

Comment: crap, sorry josh instead of adding, I by accident edited your comment away...I want to declare and use a static instance variable in objective c like you can in java...

Comment: Please describe your goal, rather than asking about technique, and we should be able to better help you do that in "the Obj-C way". EDIT: You didn't do it, I deleted my comment because I added an answer instead.

Comment: Ok so in my ViewController I have an instance variable of ClassA and I want to be able to access that instance of ClassA in all my other classes. Do you understand now :). Thanks for helping me so much.

Comment: I've added to my answer. Please let me know if you're still unclear on something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to your comment attached to the question:

If you have an instance variable in Object X, any other object that has a reference to X can access that variable through the usual means:

```
[objectX myClassAInstanceVariable];
// Or, if declared with @property
objectX.myClassAInstanceVariable;
```

If the other object *doesn't* have a reference to X, then it *can't* access the variable, no matter the state or kind of the variable. In this case, you may want to rethink your design, or see my last paragraph below about the app delegate.

---

The concept of "static" is different in Objective-C than what you may be expecting (it sounds like you're coming from experience with Java).

Objective-C doesn't really have a concept of "class variables", although it is fairly easy to simulate such a thing; this is described in the question that mathk linked to: [Objective-C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables). You declare a variable in the class's header file which is static, so that it is inaccessible outside that file, and create accessor class methods for it.

Any object that has a reference to your view controller can send messages to it. Note that in Objective-C, member variables are "protected" by default, meaning that only an instance of a class or subclasses, not other objects, can access those variables. Other objects must go through setter and getter methods.

---

Just as another option, because the background of your question is not clear, if you have some kind of a "global variable" which isn't really specific to your view controller, a better place to put it may be the application delegate*. Any object can get a reference to the delegate at any time:

```
[NSApp delegate];
```

`NSApp` is a global reference to the `NSApplication` object which is at the core of your program.

---

*Although it's certainly possible to overdo this.

Comment: hmm that sounds exactly like what im looking for! So you just construct your object in the delegate ...like in any other class? I dont get how to access it though...can you please explain a bit more :) thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a technique to be used with caution, but it can be useful. In any part of your application, you access the delegate as I indicated: `[[NSApp delegate] myInstanceVariable];` You set up that instance variable whenever you do other set up for your application delegate class; probably in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` or `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Well, thanks very much, but I just hit the cap for today so it wouldn't make a difference anyways `:D` Glad I was helpful, though!

Comment: Hey m8, im having some trouble. It didn't recognize NSApp so I tried:(GridWorldAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] but now I get a warning 'GridWorldAppDelegate' may not respond to '-delegate'?

Comment: Oh, you didn't say you were on iOS. `NSApp` is for Mac OS. If the code you just posted is accurate, you're just missing a bracket: `GridWorldAppDelegate * myAppDelegate = (GridWorldAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` should be what you need.

Comment: oh I casted the application to a delegate :P, sorry for wasting your time :(. However ever I get to thumbs up your comment again! hehe^^