# Set string from a method with class level access

Tags: objective-c, string, methods

I want to do the following

```
+(void)DoThis
{
    [textView setString:@"qwertyasdfzxcvb."];
    [textView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

However, It refuses to set the string.
Because this works,

```
-(void)DoThis
{
    [textView setString:@"qwertyasdfzxcvb."];
    [textView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

I come to the conclusion that the string refuses to be set in a method with class level access. So how do I allow a string to be set from a +(void)?

Comment: where is `textView` declared? Is it a global variable?

Comment: @ jojaba @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is the singleton/shared pattern, which allows any code to access a particular *instance* of a class without being passed that instance.

This model is used throughout Cocoa. For example, `NSFileManager` has a class method `defaultManager` which returns the shared instance of the class. You call an instance method on this shared instance by first invoking `defaultManager`, so for example to call the instance method `isDeletableFileAtPath` you write:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path]
```

In your case your `DoThis` becomes:

```
+ (void) DoThis
{
    EvDudeClass *shared = [EvDudeClass sharedInstance];
    [shared.textView setString:@"qwertyasdfzxcvb."];
    [shared.textView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

And you need to add a `sharedInstance` method to your class. There a number of ways to do this depending on how you wish to use your class - Is it a singleton? Do you just need one shared instance and other non-shared ones? Do you just want to share the instance created in the NIB? As you mention `IBOutlet` here is an implementation which does the latter:

```
static EvDudeClass *privateSharedInstance = nil;

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    privateSharedInstance = self; // save this instance so it can be shared
    // other init stuff
}

+ (EvDueClass *)sharedInstance { return privateSharedInstance; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming textView is an instance variable, there is no way to access it. At best, you can

```
+ (void)DoThis:(UITextView*)aTextView {
    [aTextView setString:@"qwertyasdfzxcvb."];
    [aTextView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: How would I hook aTextView in IB?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve exactly that requires a class method and not an instance method?

Comment: Another file will call the method.

Comment: Can't you create an instance of the class?

Comment: Without an instance of the class holding `textView`, how do you think 'textView' will exist? Can you explain the broader picture of what you are trying to achieve so that we can understand this better?

Comment: the "LoadWorld" class method in World.m calls the class method "GetInventoryItems" in Item.m Of GetInventoryItems, It figures out which items the player is holding. It then will print them into NSTextView.

Comment: print them into an instance of `NSTextView`. At some point you need to pass an instance.

Comment: @albertamg No, because PrintInventoryItems will depend on class variables

Comment: Why aren't you doing `[self loadWorld];`?

Answer (score 2):

What you are most likely trying to do is set an instance variable from a class method.  This does not work because class objects are not instances of the class and therefore cannot access instance variables.  So your method
    + (void)DoThis
does not have access to the textView *instance* variable because the class object is not an *instance* of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can not set an instance variable from a class method. If you want to declare a "class variable" you have to make a [static global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables) inside the .m file of the class because there are no class variables in Objective-C. This is a C static variable, not in the sense Java or C# consider it. Here, "static" ensures that the variable can not be used outside of that file.

Comment: You can't make a property static.

Comment: No, you can't. As I said, if you want to declare a "class variable" you have to make a static global variable inside the .m file

Comment: You can not set an instance variable from a class method because it does not make sense. Why not use an instance method?

Comment: Because I need to call the method from a different location or another class method.