# is static allocated only once?

Tags: objective-c, static

I have a **static variable** and assign some object to this **several times** like this..

```
@interface DetailViewController ()



@end
// static varable for Entry
static DirectoryEntry *dirEntry;

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


  // init entry
   dirEntry = [[DirectoryEntry alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%@ ",dirEntry);


}
```

My question is that why it's result of NSLog showing is **different** than each others...?

every time when it gets loaded, it has different **address** then, where is the **previous obj** that static pointer pointed to no that it has different address which means the previous object got 
distorted?

Thank you in advance .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6316752.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` modifier doesn't work that way.

When applied to a global variable like you're doing here, the `static` keyword just causes the variable name to only be visible within the current file. (This means that another file that declares a global variable called `dirEntry` will end up with a separate variable, not another reference to this one.)

If you want to only initialize this variable once, you'll need to ask for it explicitly:

```
static DirectoryEntry *entry = NULL;

...

    if (entry == NULL) {
        entry = [[DirectoryEntry alloc] init];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows different results since you allocate a **new** object every time `viewDidLoad` is called.

The fact that `dirEntry` is static does not make allocations to be allocated in the same address every time.

Once you reassign a new allocation the previous address is lost (if you use ARC then it will be deallocated for you) unless you assign it to another pointer variable before the new allocation.