# Emulating public/protected static vars in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, static, class-variables

The top voted answer to this SA question (  [Objective C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables) ) outlines my question quite well but to it, I'd like to add one more criteria:

#### Issue Description

1. You want your ClassA to have a ClassB class variable.
2. You are using Objective-C as programming language.
3. Objective-C does not support class variables as C++ does.
4. *I want to access ClassA's class variable from subclass ClassASub*

or even better

4a. *I want ClassA's method to access the class variable as it is, overridden in ClassASub*

Any ideas?  Or is this just bending Objective-C one step too far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a normal getter method for your class variable, and you can override it in the subclass.  Just remember to access it through the method.

```
static SomeClass *gClassVar;

@implementation ClassA

+ (SomeClass *)classVar {
    if (!gClassVar)
        gClassVar = ...;
    return gClassVar;
}

+ (...)someMethod {
    [[self classVar] doSomething];
}

@end
```

Then,

```
static SomeClass *gClassVar;

@implementation ClassASubclass

+ (SomeClass *)classVar {
    if (!gClassVar)
        gClassVar = ...;
    return gClassVar;
}

@end
```

So, when you call `[ClassA someMethod]`, it will operate on the `ClassA` instance of `classVar`.  When you call `[ClassASubclass someMethod]`, it will operate on the `ClassASubclass` instance.

The idea of having variables of any sort attached to an object (class or instance) is a feature that is kind of "stapled on" to Objective C.  Any time you want to do anything object-oriented using Objective C, start by working with methods.  (Almost) everything else is just syntactic sugar for things you can do with methods.

The concept of private / protected / public is somewhat alien to Objective C, even though access control is supported for member variables.  The best you can do for methods is to define them in a separate header (and this applies to class variables and properties, if we implement both using methods).

Comment: "Any time you want to do anything object-oriented using Objective C, start by working with methods" This is good advice. Thanks.  But what about 4a?  To clarify, the idea is that ClassA is an abstract class with a utility method, and the subs implement a certain definition used by the utility method (via the parent).  In other words, the subclasses share a common code in parent ClassA but provide bespoke data definitions.

Comment: @Hari Karam Singh: That's exactly what my code does.  Each class has its own data variable, but use the common utility methods that access the data.