# How to store property in a class that can be used in class method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS and Objective-C, I already know that in a class, the class's property you defined can only be initiated in an "instance" of that class.

But is there any mechanism in Objective-C that can store some data that can be used in the class's class method?

To be specific, I' m working on a quiet simple RPN Calculator app.

And according to the Stanford iOS Programming Dev(CS193P)'s tutorial, I create the RPN Calculator Controller's model named RPNCalculatorBrain, and there's a property `(id)program`, and a class method `+(double)runProgram:(id)program`.

`(id)program` is essentially an array contained all the operand and operation entered by user.

The instructor in that class suggest using class method so that other class (in this program's situation, a functionGraphMVC) can pass `(id)program` to this class method and get the result of the program( or, the function). So that the model RPNCalculatorBrain can be made as generic as possible.

and there's another class method `+(double)runProgram:(id) program using:(NSDictionary*)variableValues`. it is the variable edition of the above class method. So in case there's a variable (X, a, b) in `id(program)`, this class method can use `(NSDictionary *)variableValues` to interpret the variable's value.

But Personally I want to improve this method, I was just wondering if I can store Calculator's special operation (π, e) AND the variable (x) in my model (CalculatorBrain), and give a class method `+(void)setXValue();` to whoever wants use it. So I can store everything about Calculation in my model. But as far as I know, I can't store something that can be used in class method.

And store this information in NSUserDefault seems inappropriate, AND I have't read the Documentation about Core Data yet.

I know my idea seems to be a lithe strange and naive, and I certainly can use some alternate approach to do the same job, but I just want to know whether it is possible. Thanks!

If my description confuse you guys, please forgive me! My writing english is ...

Comment: The question is not clear. If you need generics then there are no generics in objective-c

Comment: Not a clear question.Make your question  more specific .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to this is to create a static global variable in the implementation file of your class, then initialize it in the `+initialize` class method ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables)), or initialize it lazily in something analogous to a class-level property accessor.

However, almost everything about the design you describe is questionable. If you really need a globally-accessible object with state, you could implement the Singleton pattern. Even then, dependency injection would be a better approach so you don't couple yourself to one concrete implementation all over the place.

Comment: Thanks, I will reconsider my design.