# Trying to put a global NSMutable Array in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I`m making an exercise, i have 2 classes Songs and Playlist, in the program i can put songs in playlist and everything is working fine, but i need to make a master playlist with all the songs that are in all the normal playlist and there is the problem.

Here is the code

```
    //
//  main.m
//  MyItunes
//
//  Created by Rodrigo López on 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 ITQ. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Songs.h"
#import "PlayList.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Songs *mySong1 = [Songs new];
        Songs *mySong2 = [Songs new];
        Songs *mySong3 = [Songs new];
        PlayList *myPlayList1=[[PlayList alloc]initWithName:@"First"];
        PlayList *myPlayList2=[[PlayList alloc]initWithName:@"Second"];


[mySong1 setTitle:@"Back In Black" setArtist:@"AC/DC" setAlbum:@"Back In Black"               setPlayt:@"4:16"];
[mySong2 setTitle:@"Medicate" setArtist:@"AFI" setAlbum:@"Crash Love" setPlayt:@"4:21"];
[mySong3 setTitle:@"Rucci" setArtist:@"Austin TV" setAlbum:@"La ultima noche" setPlayt:@"4:39"];

        [myPlayList1 addSong:mySong1];
        [myPlayList1 addSong:mySong2];
        [myPlayList2 addSong:mySong3];

        [myPlayList1 showPlayList];
        [myPlayList2 showPlayList];

         [myPlayList1 showPlayList];
         [myPlayList1 showAllSongs];

       }
    return 0;
}

    //
//  PlayList.m
//  MyItunes
//
//  Created by Rodrigo López on 6/29/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 ITQ. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PlayList.h"



@implementation PlayList


@synthesize playListarray,playListName;




-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) name  
{
  if(self)
  { 
    playListName = [NSString stringWithString: name]; 
    playListarray = [NSMutableArray array];
    playlistMaster=[NSMutableArray array ];
  }
    return self;
}




-(void) addSong: (Songs *) theSong
{



    [playListarray addObject:theSong];  

    [playlistMaster addObject:theSong];  

}

-(void) showPlayList
{
     NSLog(@"Play List: %@", self.playListName);
    for(Songs *theSong in playListarray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", theSong.title);
    }


}

-(void) showAllSongs
{
    NSLog(@"Play List: Master");
    for(Songs *theSong in playlistMaster)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", theSong.title);
    }
}



-(NSUInteger) entries 
{
    return [playListarray count]; 
}

-(void) remove: (Songs *) theSong 
{

    [playListarray removeObjectIdenticalTo:theSong];
}


@end
```

The problem is with the NSMutable array, i want to declare the array globally, but i dont know how to do it, here is the output of this program:

```
2012-06-29 19:24:06.061 MyItunes[17184:707] Play List: First
2012-06-29 19:24:06.080 MyItunes[17184:707] Back In Black
2012-06-29 19:24:06.083 MyItunes[17184:707] Medicate
2012-06-29 19:24:06.084 MyItunes[17184:707] Play List: Second
2012-06-29 19:24:06.085 MyItunes[17184:707] Rucci
2012-06-29 19:24:06.089 MyItunes[17184:707] Play List: First
2012-06-29 19:24:06.090 MyItunes[17184:707] Back In Black
2012-06-29 19:24:06.091 MyItunes[17184:707] Medicate
2012-06-29 19:24:06.091 MyItunes[17184:707] Play List: Master
2012-06-29 19:24:06.092 MyItunes[17184:707] Back In Black
2012-06-29 19:24:06.093 MyItunes[17184:707] Medicate
```

So in play list master, its missing Rucci song, hope you can help me, thank you very much, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I would make your playlistMaster a "static variable" of the PlayList implementation file as described at: [Objective C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables).  You just declare and initialize it the .m file outside of any other methods.  (Don't forget to make sure it is retained.)

I should also note that there are some memory issues in your PlayList class.  In particular, your initializer code should retain the member variables, like:

```
-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) name
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        playListName = [[NSString stringWithString: name] retain];   // NOTE:  You could also do:  [[NSString alloc] initWithString: name];
        playListarray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];    // NOTE:  You could also do:  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        playlistMaster = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];    // ditto
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you do this, you will need to add a `dealloc` method that releases each of these.  But if you don't they may be released before you try to use them.

Comment: ohhh putting the static variable was great.... it works, thanks for your time and help!!