# Accessing main class variable value in subclass

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have `mainClass` and `subClass`.

mainClass.h:

```
@interface mainClass : NSOpenGLView {
   NSBitmapImageRep *repG;
 }
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSBitmapImageRep *repG;
@end
```

mainClas.m:

```
#import "mainClass.h"

@implementation mainClass
@synthesize repG;
.....

-(void)setBitmapRepresentation {
   repG = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:someMyImage];
}
@end
```

subClass.h

```
#import "mainClass.h"

@interface subClass : mainClass {
   CIImage *someInputImage;
   CIFilter *myFilter;
}
@end
```

subClass.m

```
#import subClass.h

@implementation filteringFrontLayer

.......

-(void)setInputImageForFilter {
    someInputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:repG];
    [myFilter setValue:someInputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
}
```

And it doesn't works. It returns empty CIImage (`Invalid parameter not satisfying: ciImage != nil`). How can I access `repG` (bitmap data) with its value (value is set in mainClass) in my subClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also access the property with its accessor:

```
someInputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithBitmapImageRep:[self repG]];
```

Comment: It still returns empty `repG`. I added `NSLog(@"repG.Height:%ld, repG.Width:%ld", [self repG].pixelsHigh, [self repG].pixelsWide);` and it returns `repG.Height:0, repG.Width:0`

Comment: Could you please put the same logs inside setBitmapRepresentation. I'd like to make sure that they are set initially.

Comment: What do you mean with `setBitmapRepresentation`? By the way, same `NSLog` returns `repG.Height:2000, repG.Width:3200` in main class at the same time

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of subClass running at the same time? Maybe you are seeing logs of different instances ?

Comment: No. All the time my main class is running. The one and only subclass runs only when user selection changes

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have two objects running, one is an instance of the mainClass, the other one is an instance of subClass, is that right? In that case, the subclass instance would of course not have the same value for repG.

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to make it having same value for repG?

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables or create a singleton to share that variable.