# understanding class and instance methods variables

Tags: objective-c

In my code, i have a class , `mainClass` , which has an instance method `-(void)record` .
In the interface of  `mainClass` , i have instance variable,which used by this method.

Now, i know that every time i am creating a new instance of the class with :

```
mainClass *instance=[mainClass alloc];
```

its creating a new place in memory to all this class variables , and now if i do

```
[instance record];
```

it will create all the variables that are in `record` but they will be new once.

Now lets say i want to call from an outside class to `record` , and change/use its variables
not create new once, but use the once already created in the `mainClass`.

whats the best way of doing this, and what it has to do with a class method ?
Should this method be a class method? if yes , why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it accessible, instance and permanent changed you have to make it static, will answer your next question

[Objective C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables)