# Integer to be accessed over several classes?

Tags: xcode, ios6, int

Im making a quiz based game in which has multiple view controllers that all share a "Skip Question" button. The user will have 3 skips and can purchase more at any time. I'm trying to create a class in which i can use a sharedInstance that i can use to add skips or use one, but what I don't under stand is how to retrieve the amount of skips they have on one of my view controllers. For example:

My Integer Class .h

```
int skips;
```

My Integer Class .m

```
skips = 3;
```

My ViewController.h

```
int vcSkips;
```

My ViewController.m

```
vcSkips = [MyIntegerclass skips];
```

Just an example. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C Static Class Level variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a static variable:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/

Comment: Google "Objective C Static Variable" - possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables