# Is it correct to use objc_setAssociatedObject for class object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, static, static-variables

Is it correct to use `objc_setAssociatedObject` for class object?

We often simulate class variables using static variables like that:
[Objective C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables)
but, can we use Associated objects as alternative?

```
objc_setAssociatedObject([self class], &STRING_KEY, myString, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

Comment: Yeah, but it will be harder to understand for those who will maintain your code. You should use objc_setAssociatedObject when you need to add a dynamic component data but you don't know what precisely kind of data / name to add at compile time. If you know it at compile time, you still can use the old global technique ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a class object is a full-fledged object, so you can do anything to it that you can do with a regular object.

However, it is clearer and simpler to use a global variable.

p.s. Associating it with `[self class]` is not the same as using a global variable, because `[self class]` gives you the actual class of the current object, which may vary as this method is inherited by subclasses. Whereas with a global variable it would always be the same variable.

Comment: In my case, I have a base class with many subclasses, each subclass needs a unique class ivar (so to speak), so this is actually the perfect solution for me!