# How to annotate Objective-C APIs for use in Swift (e.g. return types)

Tags: objective-c, swift

According to the Xcode release notes, Apple has been "auditing" their existing APIs to remove implicitly unwrapped optionals. That means that instead of `T!`, their APIs will return `T` or `T?` where appropriate.

Where do they do this? How can I annotate/wrap my existing Objective-C code (especially libraries) to make it cleaner to use from Swift?

Comment: Compare https://devforums.apple.com/message/1020251 (Developer login required).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Xcode 6.3/Swift 1.2

Xcode 6.3 added official support for annotating nullability in Objective-C.

#### Nullability

The nullability of a value can be declared by annotating the type with the keywords `__nullable`, `__nonnull` and `__null_unspecified` (the default). In properties and methods the keywords are `nullable`, `nonnull` and `null_unspecified`.

Examples from the Xcode release notes

```
   - (void)registerNib:(nonnull UINib *)nib
forCellReuseIdentifier:(nonnull NSString *)identifier;

- (nullable UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath)indexPath;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain, nullable) UIView *backgroundView;
```

#### Changing the default

`null_unspecified` (which translates to `T!`) is the default for all existing code. A useful feature is the ability to change the default for sections of your API.

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
// nonnull is the default here
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

This removes a lot of noise, since methods that accept and handle nil usually are the exception, not the rule. Personally, I would use this for all audited APIs.

#### null_resettable

`null_resettable` is an additional annotation that is used for the uncommon case where you can *set* a property to nil, but it will never *be* nil (because it resets to a default value).

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain, null_resettable) UIColor *tintColor;
```

Personally, I would avoid this behavior for new code. The hybrid nature of such properties isn't a good fit for Swift.

### Xcode 7/Swift 2 (Beta)

Xcode 7 adds support for annotating generic types in Objective-C.

#### Generic type annotations for collections

`NSArray`, `NSSet` and `NSDictionary` (which are automatically bridged to Swift's `Array`, `Set` and `Dictionary` can be annotated with the type of their contents.

```
@property NSArray<NSString *> *stringArray;
@property NSSet<NSString *> *stringSet;
@property NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *stringDict;
```

There's also the `__kindof` keyword that tells the Objective-C compiler to be less strict and allow downcasting. But it doesn't affect the Swift side.

#### Generic type annotations for custom classes

```
@interface MyArray1<__covariant T> : NSObject
- (void)addObject:(T)object;
@end

@interface MyArray2<__covariant T : NSObject *> : NSObject
- (void)addObject:(T)object;
@end

@interface MyArray3<__covariant T : id<NSCopying>> : NSObject
- (void)addObject:(T)object;
@end
```

The `@implementation` doesn't know about `T` and uses `id`/`NSObject *`/`id<NSCopying>` as it always did.

Comment: No, as I said, the underscores are not used in properties and methods. It works just like `__weak` and `weak` (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944361/ios-weak-vs-weak).

Answer (score 12):

I believe there's a way to do this at the moment. It looks like the information is being compiled to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
```

in files like

```
UIKit.apinotesc 
UIKit.swiftdoc 
UIKit.swiftmodule
```

The `*.swiftmodule` classes are generated by Xcode as part of the swift build but the additional information may be in the `.apinotesc` file, which there doesn't appear to be a documented form of generating it at the moment.

However, the `swift` command has an `-apinotes` option, which is used to generate this. You can see from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/UIKit.apinotesc` that you can parse this with:

```
xcrun swift -apinotes -binary-to-yaml  -o=- /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/UIKit.apinotesc
```

This generates a YAML file looking like:

```
Classes:         
  - Name:            NSFileProviderExtension
    Availability:    available
    AvailabilityMsg: ''
    Methods:         
      - Selector:        'URLForItemWithPersistentIdentifier:'
        MethodKind:      Instance
        Nullability:     [ N ]
        NullabilityOfRet: U
        Availability:    available
        AvailabilityMsg: ''
```

If I were a betting man (and I'm not), I'd say that the MethodKind determines whether it's an `Instance` or a `Class` and that the Nullability is being used by Swift to determine whether it's an optional or not. I would suspect:

- `U` - (implicitly) unwrapped optional
- `O` - optional
- `N` - non-optional?

These are wild guesses though.

Comment: FYI this is private functionality subject to change in future releases without warning. This is not how we intend to expose this functionality to 3rd parties like yourself.

Comment: Happy to believe that - it was a useful exercise in understanding where Swift was getting this information from though :)