# Explicitly importing Objective-C properties into Swift as optionals

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**Update: As of Xcode 6.3 this is now possible via [nullability annotations](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/).**

I've been wondering if anyone has figured out a way to explicitly import Obj-C properties into Swift as a optional.

**The Problem**

Consider the following ObjC class:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject* potentiallyNil;
@end
```

This is great and all, but when you go to use it in Swift, Xcode tends to import the property as either an instance proper or as an implicitly unwrapped optional.

I've seen this come in as both

```
class Foo : NSObject {
var potentiallyNil : NSObject
}
```

*as well as*

```
class Foo : NSObject {
var potentiallyNil : NSObject!
}
```

Now here's the problem with that - within Swift, you've now got this ugly problem of *knowing* that your property may be nil, but having to avoid the beauty of implicit optional conversion. You're left with one of the following options:

An explicit nil check...

```
if(potentiallyNil == nil) {
  bar()
}
```

Or a manual conversion to an optional type with an unwrap - also ugly...

```
let manuallyWrappedPotentiallyNil : NSObject? = potentiallyNil
if let unwrapped = manuallyWrappedPotentiallyNil {
   bar();
}
```

Both of these seem far from ideal. It seems to me there MUST be a way around this! In fact, as @matt has pointed out, Apple has done this themselves throughout the betas while "auditing for optional compliance". Can we do the same?

**The Question**

It boils down to this: Given the ObjC property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject* potentiallyNil;
```

is there a way to cause this to be imported to Swift with the signature

```
var potentiallyNil : NSObject?
```

Many thanks to all you other iOS/OS X devs out there.

Comment: It must be possible because the Cocoa APIs do it; they distinguish between `Type`, `Type!`, and `Type?`. The APIs have been hand-tweaked for this. They don't always choose correctly, but they do it. But I don't know _how_ they do it. Perhaps there's some marking they attach to the type...

Comment: @matt, yeah, this is exactly my point. Through the betas they've been "auditing" the APIs for optional compliance. I'm hopeful that there is a way that us lowly end-user developers can do this. Hopefully the answer is not "It's hardcoded in UIKit!"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to annotate Objective-C APIs for use in Swift (e.g. return types)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747377/how-to-annotate-objective-c-apis-for-use-in-swift-e-g-return-types)

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28420974/860000) Xcode 6.3β and Swift 1.2 add support for this feature with `__nullable` , et al.

Comment: @BrianNickel correct. Forgot to update the question - marking it as closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of asking this question, this was not possible. However, in Xcode 6.3, there is a new [nullability annotation](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/) feature to enable this previously private functionality. Question is therefore no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the API interface code you'll see that there are both Swift and Objective C versions of classes. So I guess that's Apple's solution to the issue?

Comment: Likely so. Sadly, this doesn't help anyone else. Hopefully Apple will introduce a solution we can take advantage of soon.