# collectionView optional in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Reading the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewController/collectionView) on the `collectionView` of a `UICollectionViewController`, it appears to be optional, as denoted by the `?`. This seems odd to me, as if there is a possibility that the `collectionView` could be `nil` and then the `UICollectionViewController` would seem to be pointless. In regards to the `tableView` of the `UITableViewController`, the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/tableView) states that it cannot be `nil`, as it is marked with a `!`.

My question is, why would the `collectionView` be optional, and what must I consider when using a `UICollectionViewController`? Must I be concerned that the `collectionView` will be `nil` and, in addition, at what point is the `collectionView` initialized? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a controller is created all its views start out as `nil` because they haven't been created yet – iOS lazy loads as much as it can for performance reasons. When a view controller's views have been fully loaded its `viewDidLoad()` method gets called so you know it's all safe to use.

Comment: So what's the difference between the collectionView and and tableView?

Comment: I'm not sure why one is ? and the other is !, but your statement that "the Apple Documentation states that it cannot be nil, as it is marked with a !" is incorrect: `UITableView` cannot be nil, but `UITableView?` and `UITableView!` both can be.

Comment: i believe what Apple meant was that after initialization, tableView cannot be nil

Answer (score 0):

When I write a view controller I try to create my views in `loadView` method so until view is needed all view properties are `nil` and thats why they all need to be optionals. I assume it's the same with `UICollectionViewController` and `UITableViewController`.

And the reason why there's `?` for collection and `!` for table? I think it's pretty simple. `UITableViewController` is much older than `UICollectionViewController` and view properties of both are annotated differently (`nullable` vs. `null_resetable`) which results in different behavior when using Swift.

Comment: is `nullable` `!` while `null_restable` `?` ?

Comment: I assume it's the other way, `nullable` results in `?` and `null_resetable` in `!` according to the description from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28420974/2294228