# Objective-C: class variable at run time?

Tags: objective-c

There are several questions that seem similar to this (e.g. [Objective C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables)) and that I read, but I am still confused. Notably, various answers seem to deal differently with the call to `initialize`.

I have a class `Foo`. At runtime, my app interrogates the back-end to find out what "class parameters" should be used for `Foo` (i.e. these params will be shared across all instances of `Foo`). I know how to deal with the back-end etc. But I don't know if my Objective-C approach is correct. I should say: it does work. But again: I am not sure what I am doing.

**EDIT:** *I thought it worked. But from time to time, I get a strange exception:*
`libsystem_platform.dylib _os_lock_recursive_abort`.

It happens in initialize when I alloc/init the `NSDictionary`.

```
Foo.h:

+ (NSDictionary *)parameters;
+ (void)setParameters:(NSDictionary *)params;

Foo.m:

static NSDictionary *parameters = nil;

@implementation Foo

+ (NSDictionary *)parameters{
    return parameters;
}

+ (void)setParameters:(NSDictionary *)params
{
    parameters = params;
}

+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];
    if ((self == [Foo self]) && !parameters) // Is this right??
        parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
}

@end

... somewhere else, in another class ...

[Foo setParameters:dictionaryOfParams];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor improvement.

According to Apples `+ (void)initialize` documentation:

> initialize is invoked only once per class.

As you are ignoring the `initialize` when it is being called from a subclass you could remove the `!parameters` from the If condition. Because you know for sure that it will run only once.

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I just added a comment: I get a strange exception from time to time. So I guess something is not right...